# Static constructor registers object constructor => not called

Tags: c#, generics, static-constructor

I wanted to use a static constructor in derived classes to register object constructor lambdas for those classes to be called when passing a certain `Type` object.

Since a static constructor is only called just before the first object of that class is created BUT I want to use the result of the static constructor to determine what kind of object to create, this mechanism fails, the constructor lambda is not found.

Is there any way out of this?

```
public abstract class Cacheable
{
    // ... details do not matter ...
}

public class Series: Cacheable
{
    // ... details do not matter ...
}

public abstract class CacheableViewForm
{
    static Dictionary<Type, Func<CacheableViewForm>> cacheableViewFormConstructors = new Dictionary<Type, Func<CacheableViewForm>>();

    protected static void Register<CacheableViewFormClass, CacheableClass>()
        where CacheableViewFormClass: CacheableViewForm, new()
        where CacheableClass: Cacheable
    {
        cacheableViewFormConstructors[typeof(CacheableClass)] = (() => new CacheableViewFormClass());
    }

    public static CacheableViewForm CreateFromTargetType(Type cacheableType)
    {
        return cacheableViewFormConstructors[cacheableType]();
    }

    // ... details do not matter ...
}

public class SeriesViewForm: CacheableViewForm
{
    static SeriesViewForm() {Register<SeriesViewForm, Series>();}

    // ... details do not matter ...
}

// fails because CacheableViewForm.Register<> has not been executed yet!
CacheableViewForm newForm = CacheableViewForm.CreateFromTargetType(typeof(Series));
```

Comment: "Is there any way out of this?" - I'd try to find a different approach, basically. Relying on exactly when static constructors will be executed is going to make the code hard to reason about. Why not just have a separate method that you call explicitly?

Comment: (Note that static constructors are called in other situations btw - such as static methods being called on the type. There doesn't have to be an instance created. But using the type as a generic type argument does *not* trigger the static constructor, as you've noted.)

Comment: Well, the intention behind that mechanism was to keep the "registration call" close to the respective class definition (in this case SeriesViewForm). So if I need to add another class derived from CacheableViewForm, I know I have to add that call to that class. If the registration is done e.g. in my MainForm, then I will have to remember to do edits in two different places (MainForm AND CacheableViewForm derived class) in order to extend the whole thing.

Comment: for your information a static constructor does not take access modifiers or have parameters. A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced. A static constructor cannot be called directly

Comment: @sayahimad: yeah i knew that, thank you.

Comment: Yes, which is nonideal - but does have the benefit of working. Another approach would be to use attributes to tie the relevant classes together, and then examine them with reflection on startup.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to move initialization (from the static constructor of the derived classes) to the static constructor of the base class (which gets called automatically before executing my first call to the `CreateFromTargetType` method) and using reflection in there to examine the derived classes. In the derived classes I defined static methods (`TargetType`) which return the specific `Type` they are operating on.

Neither elegant nor compact, and certainly not super fast, but it allows me to keep the association between derived class (e.g. `SeriesViewForm`) and the data type it operates on (`typeof(Series)`) close together (in the same class definition).

```
public abstract class CacheableViewForm: Form
{
    static Dictionary<Type, Func<CacheableViewForm>> CacheableViewFormConstructors = new Dictionary<Type, Func<CacheableViewForm>>();

    static CacheableViewForm()
    {
        var allAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        foreach(Assembly assembly in allAssemblies)
        {
            Type[] cacheableViewFormTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(t => typeof(CacheableViewForm).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t != typeof(CacheableViewForm)).ToArray();

            foreach (Type cacheableViewFormType in cacheableViewFormTypes)
            {
                MethodInfo mi = cacheableViewFormType.GetMethod("TargetType");
                Type cacheableType = (Type)mi.Invoke(null, null);
                Func<CacheableViewForm> ctorDelegate = (() => (CacheableViewForm)(Activator.CreateInstance(cacheableViewFormType)));
                CacheableViewFormConstructors[cacheableType] = ctorDelegate;
            }
        }
    }

    public static CacheableViewForm CreateFromTargetType(Type cacheableType)
    {
        return CacheableViewFormConstructors[cacheableType]();
    }
}

public class SeriesViewForm: CacheableViewForm
{
    public static Type TargetType() {return typeof(Series);}

    // ...
}
```